# interbank market rates - missing data

Tags: interbank-rates

I took EU market rates here: https://www.banque-france.fr/en/economics-statistics/rates/main-euro-area-interbank-market-rates.html

As you can see (Eonia 05/13/1999 for example) there is non defined and non available data. I know that for prices you can't easily interpolate data because you will modify volatility in doing so. You need to use more complex techniques (kalman filter ?).

My question is: how can I handle missing data for markets rates ?
Does it depends on what you want to do with your data ? (I want to predict clients comportement based on short terms rates).

Answer (score 1):

Of cause, the best solution is to fill out the missing holes, in this case head over to the [ECB Statistical Bank](http://sdw.ecb.europa.eu/quickview.do?SERIES_KEY=198.EON.D.EONIA_TO.RATE&start=12-05-1999&end=14-05-1999&submitOptions.x=44&submitOptions.y=11&trans=N), and get a higher quality dataset or fill the holes, in your existing one.

Taking your EONIA example, I would simply take the difference between the rate before and after the missing spot(s), and divide it by the missing spots and increment the before rate with the found coefficient.

However it is important the you disclose that some of the data you/your model rely on have interpolated data points, and this should be incorporated into the model accuracy.
I would recommend to trigger a warning if the change between the missing points is larger than a fixed amount e.g. if [2009-01-21 where to be missing](http://sdw.ecb.europa.eu/quickview.do?SERIES_KEY=198.EON.D.EONIA_TO.RATE&start=20-01-2009&end=22-01-2009&submitOptions.x=48&submitOptions.y=14&trans=N), the difference between 2009-01-20 and 2009-01-22 would be 0.899 which is quite a drop, and might severely affect your model.

BTW: Take look at the [one-size-fits-all interpolation methods](http://se.mathworks.com/help/finance/fillts.html) of missing data from time series in Matlabs Financial Toolbox.

Comment: Should I just remove week-ends/banks holidays or interpolate them ?

Comment: In case of weekends and bank holidays, you should use the last set rate, as that would be the one valid for the weekend/holiday. Only use interpolated rates when they is missing in the dataset.

Comment: Thakns for your answer. As a non-native english speaker I would highly appreciate a short illustration of the "Taking your EONIA example, I would simply take the difference between the rate before and after the missing spot(s), and divide it by the missing spots and increment the before rate with the found coefficient." part of your answer with number.